# Android read NFC while keeping Bluetooth connection active

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bluetooth, nfc

In my app I have an active Bluetooth connection, and I am reading simultaneously NFC tags. 
My issue is that when I read an NFC tag, the Bluetooth connection is lost.

I am using parallel asynctasks both on the Bluetooth and the NFC read asynctasks, with:

.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)

Any ideas on what I am missing?

EDIT: It seems that on scanning an NFC tag, the enableForegroundDispatch(), is destroying the Activities running in the background. Any way to change the way that enableForegroundDispatch() works, and not kill the rest of the Activities?

EDIT2:That is my manifest declaration

```
<activity
    android:name="mainActivities.ScreensClasses.NFCReader"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_nfcreader" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On resume I call : setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
On Pause I call:  stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);

And that is my foregrounddispatch:

```
                  public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
    String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

    filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
    } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
    }
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
}
```

And I am reading NDEF tags. On my foregrounddispattch I have tried different intent filters, but it seems that it makes any difference.

So with this code, when I scan an NDEF tag containing a string, all my applications activities are destroyed(onDestroy is called)

Comment: What exception is the bluetooth code throwing? NFC IO are blocking operations, so it could be that you're not accounting for that.

Comment: What device is the device you are testing? Have you tried a different brand/manufacturer.

Comment: @Olaia: I am testing on a Moto G4 Play, and I do not have access to any different model at this point.

Comment: @henrycjc: I do not get any exception, just the connection closes by itself even before getting the data of the NFC.

Comment: Do you filter for NFC intents in AndroidManifest.xml? If yes (or if no + you have an AAR on the tag), are you sure that the foreground dispatch is setup correctly? What Android versions do you intend to use?

Comment: @MichaelRoland: Yes I filter the NFC intents in the Manifest, and I believe that foreground dispatch is setup based on documentation. It seems though that every activity of my app is destroyed when I scan a tag, apart from the activity that is implementing the foreground dispatch.

Comment: @Kostis4444 Then you should definitely show us the relevant manifest sections, the code where you register & where you deregister the foreground dispatch, what type of tag you use, and what data you have on the tag. Without that information its impossible to tell what might go wrong in your app.

Comment: @Kostis4444 Does it change anything if you use the activity context instead of the application context above (i.e. use `activity` where you currently have `activity.getApplicationContext()`)? Also, does it change anything if you set the tech-list argument to `null`? You could also try setting the last two arguments of `enableForegroundDispatch()` to `null`. However, if that helps, you most probably *do* have an Android Application Record on the tag.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Many thanks for those ideas, but unfortunately it still has the same behaviour, and my other activities are destroyed when I scan a new tag.

Comment: @Kostis4444 Could you show us the details of the intent that you receive in onNewIntent() as a result of the foreground dispatch? (I.e. action, category, datatype, extras, etc.)